# How to extract text from image using openCV or OCR tesseract?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, ocr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android OCR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr)

i'm currently doing a project on text recognition based on a image capture in android phone. I want to ask how the text can be extracted from image?

Does have any openCV or OCR tesseract tutorial for extracting ?

Comment: This question was asked many times. Take a look at this one: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1702/text-recognition-for-android-app/1704#1704

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgth0qxTgYY

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way (maybe not the ideal) is to implement the following steps:

- Use OpenCV to **[detect the paper sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection/8863060#8863060) or the [text area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10232763/176769)**;
- Perform any processing necessary to **[deskew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838487/executing-cvwarpperspective-for-a-fake-deskewing-on-a-set-of-cvpoint) the image** (if necessary);
- **Save the image to disk as TIFF**;
- and finally, **call Tesseract cmd-line application** passing the TIFF image as parameter to start the text recognition process.