# How to detect text area on image and save it to another image for preparing OCR in iOS?

Tags: ios, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I use `GPUImage` to convert image to `Black&White`, and then I use `TesseractOCRiOS` to scan text on that image, but output is not good result. So I want to detect text on image and save to another image with text only to prepare for `OCR` to have good result.

Comment: You can find text with Opencv [Scene Text Detection](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html) and the crop the subimages with text.

Comment: Thanks @Miki, but I don't know the way to write it in `Objective-C`. Could you write a demo small app?

Comment: GPUImage doesn't have a simple method which you can use to detect text. That's a very complex problem.

Which methods did you try? 

Several methods are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206526/how-to-detect-text-area-from-image

If you plan to use OpenCV - you can use it with C/C++ only.