# How to check if a image has any text or not?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr

I'm looking for a simple solution that would return a boolean if ANY kind of English text is present in an image file. I wish to use this to detect memes. For example, the following file should be detected as an image with text.

[image: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d5/13/4b/d5134b891d3903d0f272f6430014f089.gif]

I've come across elaborate machine learning techniques using OpenCV but I haven't been able to fully implement it. Is there any quicker, simpler, and just as effective solution for this?

I look forward to your valuable feedback!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect text area in an image using python and opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771263/detect-text-area-in-an-image-using-python-and-opencv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed simple way with opencv and pytessaract after installing you will only need to use a few lines in order to get the text

**pip install opencv-python**

**pip install pytesseract**

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('yourimage.jpeg')   

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

[Read Text from Image with One Line of Python Code](https://towardsdatascience.com/read-text-from-image-with-one-line-of-python-code-c22ede074cac)

Also if you don't like the first way you can use Google vision, keep in mind it will return Json and you will extract what you need.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

[Python Client for Google Cloud Vision](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/index.html)

Comment: I've ready tried these simple solutions with tesseract. But most of the times the results are incorrect and nowhere true

Comment: Have you considered cutting just the relevant place? it will help tesserac. For example, keep just the button half part if you need memes

Comment: @SaiChivukula google vision has great results so you may want to consider it also

Comment: Thanks. I'll try cropping out the irrelevant part. I've looked at Google's vision as well. It seems quite nice but its a paid alternative.

Comment: Try to recognize also the inverted picture. This is the case for light letters on a dark background, as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pytesseract` python package for get text form the images. You can easily install like `pip install pytesseract`

Here is the example code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
image = cv2.imread('test.jpeg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
print(text)
```

Here is my sample image 
[image]

So, the output should be like

```
IS BITCOIN
GOING TO
$20.000
BY CHRISTMAS?
```

Comment: I've ready tried these simple solutions with tesseract. But most of the times the results are incorrect and nowhere near 90% accuracy

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OpenCV` and `pytesseract` to perform your task.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
img = cv2.imread('YOUR_IMAGE_PATH')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Comment: You can find out more details here.https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-text-from-images-with-python-db9b87fe432b

Comment: I've ready tried these simple solutions with tesseract. But most of the times the results are incorrect and nowhere near 90% accuracy