# Python make bigger gaps between words in an image

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following image:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("without_space.png")
img.show()
```

[image]

And I wish to increase the gaps between the words to look like this:

[image]

I thought about converting the image to NumPy:

```
img = numpy.ndarray(img)
```

than increasing the x-axis and the y-axis of the array to leave room for increasing the gaps:

```
def increase_padding(img):
    np_arr = np.asarray(img)

    shape = np_arr.shape

    y = shape[0]
    colors = shape[2]
    zeros = np.zeros([y,20,colors], dtype=np.uint8)
    zeros[:,:,3] = 255
    np_arr = np.append(np_arr,zeros, axis=1)
    np_arr = np.append(zeros, np_arr, axis=1)

    shape = np_arr.shape

    x = shape[1]
    colors = shape[2]

    zeros = np.zeros([20,x,colors], dtype=np.uint8)
    zeros[:,:,3] = 255
    np_arr = np.append(np_arr,zeros, axis=0)
    np_arr = np.append(zeros, np_arr, axis=0)

    return np_arr
```

this is the result:

```
 img = increase_padding(img)
 img.show()
```

[image]

The image have more room to space out the words, but now I'm stuck.
any ideas?

Comment: You would need some way to identify the words and then insert the space in between the words rather than at the left/right and top/bottom of the image. In general I don't think it's a trivial matter to find the words in an image but in this example it looks like some simple rules might work (especially if the image is literally black and white, i.e. color values of either 0 or 255 and nothing else).

Comment: There is a `numpy` function for padding [`np.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html). A solution to your question has to identify letters and words in an image. That is a complex program not an answerable question.

Comment: Detecting the [bounding boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771263/detect-text-area-in-an-image-using-python-and-opencv) of text is actually easier than I thought.

Comment: Maybe you could say what you are actually trying to achieve by doing this please? There could be much better ways. Do you know the text in the image, for example?

Comment: I don't know the text upfront. But all texts come in the format I showed above.
Black on white

Answer (score 0):

Your padding mechanism is not so good, my version is following

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

ROI_number = 0
factor = 40
decrement = 20
margin = 3

#sorting code source
#https://gist.github.com/divyaprabha123/bfa1e44ebdfc6b578fd9715818f07aec
def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
    '''
    sort_contours : Function to sort contours
    argument:
        cnts (array): image contours
        method(string) : sorting direction
    output:
        cnts(list): sorted contours
        boundingBoxes(list): bounding boxes
    '''
    # initialize the reverse flag and sort index
    reverse = False
    i = 0

    # handle if we need to sort in reverse
    if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        reverse = True

    # handle if we are sorting against the y-coordinate rather than
    # the x-coordinate of the bounding box
    if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        i = 1

    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to
    # bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
    (cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
        key=lambda b:b[1][i], reverse=reverse))

    # return the list of sorted contours and bounding boxes
    return (cnts, boundingBoxes)

image = cv2.imread("test.png")

#use a black container of same shape to construct new image with gaps
container = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9, 9), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 25)

# Dilate to combine adjacent text contours
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=4)

# Find contours, highlight text areas, and extract ROIs
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

#sort so that order remain preserved
cnts = sort_contours(cnts)[0]

for c in cnts:
    ROI_number += 1
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    print(area)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    
    x -= margin
    y -= margin
    w += margin
    h += margin

    #extract region of interest e.g. the word
    roi = image[y : y + h, x : x + w].copy()
    factor -= decrement
        
    x = x - factor

    #copy the words from the original image to container image with gap factor
    container[y : y + h, x : x + w] = roi

cv2.imshow('image', container)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The output is below, I assume for other images you will have to optimize this code to automatically find optimum threshold values.

[image]

What I did is following

1. Extract contours using a threshold value
2. Sort contours left to right for correct words order
3. Create empty container (new image of same size as original)
4. Copy all words from original to new container with padding

Answer (score 0):

To move the words in the bitmap, you will need to determine the bounding boxes that correspond to those areas.

The horizontal dimensions of these bounding boxes can be recognized by horizontal spacing.

Your first step is to "aggregate" the image along the horizontal axis, taking the maximum (this will mark all columns containing at least one pixel).

```
horizontal = np_arr.max(axis=0)
```

You then need to determine the 0-runs in this array that are at least a given length. These will be the margins and the spaces between words. (The threshold needs to be high enough to skip over spaces between letters.)

Finally, the parts between these 0-runs will be the areas that contain words.