# How can I detect text area in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, google-colaboratory

This is code frome [Detect text area in an image using python and opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771263/detect-text-area-in-an-image-using-python-and-opencv)

This my picture

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, adaptive threshold
image = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/project/test/R1/a_5.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,17,23)

# Dilate to combine adjacent text contours
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)

# Find contours, highlight text areas, and extract ROIs
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 10000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
        # ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        # cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        # ROI_number += 1

cv2_imshow(thresh)
cv2_imshow(dilate)
cv2_imshow(image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The result is
[image]
[image]
[image]

But I want it cover all my word like this

[image]

please Help me to complete this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to lower the threshold to get the last letter. Second, we combine all the rectangles by taking the minimum of `xmin`, `ymin` and maximum of `xmax`, `ymax`:

```
ROI_number = 0
xmin, ymin = float('inf'), float('inf')
xmax, ymax = float('-inf'), float('-inf')
hall, wall = 0, 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 1000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        xmin, ymin = min(x, xmin), min(y, ymin)
        xmax, ymax = max(x+w, xmax), max(y+h, ymax)

w = xmax - xmin
h = ymax - ymin
cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin), (xmin + w, ymin + h), (36,255,12), 3)
        # ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        # cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        # ROI_number += 1

cv2_imshow(thresh)
cv2_imshow(dilate)
cv2_imshow(image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Update** for two words, we combine rectangles conditioned on y. Note you may need to change `thresh` to find a good one:

```
thresh1 = 50
thresh2 = 100
ROI_number = 0
rectangles = []
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > thresh1:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        rectangles.append((x, y, w, h))
        # ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        # cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        # ROI_number += 1

rectangles = sorted(rectangles,key=lambda x: x[1])
start = rectangles[0]
yc0 = start[1]+start[3]//2
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = start[0], start[1], start[0] +start[2], start[1] + start[3]
for idx, rect in enumerate(rectangles[1:]):
  yc = rect[1] + rect[3]//2
  if abs(yc0 - yc) > thresh2:
    w = xmax - xmin
    h = ymax - ymin
    cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin), (xmin + w, ymin + h), (36,255,12), 3)
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = rect[0], rect[1], rect[0] +rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]
    yc0 = yc
  else:
    x, y, w, h = rect
    xmin, ymin = min(x, xmin), min(y, ymin)
    xmax, ymax = max(x+w, xmax), max(y+h, ymax)
w = xmax - xmin
h = ymax - ymin
cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin), (xmin + w, ymin + h), (36,255,12), 3);


cv2_imshow(thresh)
cv2_imshow(dilate)
cv2_imshow(image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: It's work!! How about 2 word like answer below?

Comment: didn't understand.

Comment: this answer amounts to `cv.convexHull`. -- giving each word its own bounding box requires you to decide how far apart lines may be to still be considered one word.

Comment: `convexHull` is to for connected lines, not for disconnected lines.

Comment: @NaraNart I updated the answer, now it works for two words

Comment: @coder00 Please tell me about ROI 2 words TT